# How to add [UP] -3 [DOWN] controls to switch between layers on a custom map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've been googling for days now, and getting kind of frustrated.. I hope anyone can help me!

What I'm trying to achieve is the controls (as shown below), which if pressing the DOWN button for example, it will show the map layer which is one "floor" below the current, and set the "0" to "-1".

[image]
<---

My current map looks like this, and I want to be able to go up and down on "floors".

**This is the GROUND level**
[image]

**And this is -1 floor, the level beneath the above image**
[image]

I have all the images etc, I have basic understanding of Leaflet, but I can't figure out how to add this control and make it load the desired level.

Anyone that could help me, or lead me in the right direction?

Kind Regards,
Andreas.

Comment: Have you already created the control?

Comment: No, I've read many tutorials about it, but half of them add the control to the right side of the screen. I'm losing patience, don't know which tutorial/doc to read.

Comment: Well, I do have the zoom control on the map. That works glorious, but now I wanna be able to switch the ground levels

Comment: Here is current version: [my current map](http://prntscr.com/racpxd)
The 1+0 control to the left is a try, but they just zoom in 1 or out 0.. dunno how to code it.

Comment: I suggest reading https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html , then https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Zoom.js (for the code to create the buttons etc). Create one `LayerGroup` per level, feed a data structure with those to the custom control. Have the control remove a layergroup and add a new one whenever the up/down buttons are clicked.

Comment: Control position is an option which applies to any subclass of `L.Control`: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#control-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a working controler for you (but it is not designed):

```
L.LayerControl = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'topright',
        layerIdx: 0,
        //control position - allowed: 'topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft', 'bottomright'
    },

    initialize: function(layers, options) {
        this.layers = layers;
        L.setOptions(this, options);
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        this.map = map;
        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-control layercontrol');
        var buttonUp = L.DomUtil.create('a', '', container);
            buttonUp.innerHTML = '^';
        this.text = L.DomUtil.create('a', '', container);
        this.text.innerHTML = this.layers[this.options.layerIdx].name;
        this.text.style.fontWeight = '900';
        var buttonDown = L.DomUtil.create('a', '', container);
            buttonDown.innerHTML = 'v';
        L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(container);
        L.DomEvent.on(buttonUp, 'click', this._clickUp, this);
        L.DomEvent.on(buttonDown, 'click', this._clickDown, this);

        this._removeAllLayers();
        this.map.addLayer(this.layers[this.options.layerIdx].layer);

        return container;
    },
    _clickUp : function () {
        if(this.layers.length -1 > this.options.layerIdx){  
            this.map.fire('layercontrolUp', {layer: this.layers[this.options.layerIdx].layer, name: this.layers[this.options.layerIdx].name});
            this.options.layerIdx++;
            this.text.innerHTML = this.layers[this.options.layerIdx].name;
            this._removeAllLayers();
            this.map.addLayer(this.layers[this.options.layerIdx].layer);
        }
    },
    _clickDown : function () {
        if(0 < this.options.layerIdx){  
            this.map.fire('layercontrolDown', {layer: this.layers[this.options.layerIdx].layer, name: this.layers[this.options.layerIdx].name});
            this.options.layerIdx--;
            this.text.innerHTML = this.layers[this.options.layerIdx].name;
            this._removeAllLayers();
            this.map.addLayer(this.layers[this.options.layerIdx].layer);
        }
    },
    _removeAllLayers: function(){
        //removing all layers from the map where added from the control
        this.layers.forEach(function(controlLayer){
            this.map.removeLayer(controlLayer.layer);       
        });
    }
});


var fg1 = new L.FeatureGroup();
fg1.addLayer(L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup());


var fg2 = new L.FeatureGroup();
fg2.addLayer(L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).bindPopup("I am a circle."));


var fg3 = new L.FeatureGroup();
fg3.addLayer(L.polygon([
        [51.509, -0.08],
        [51.503, -0.06],
        [51.51, -0.047]
    ]).bindPopup("I am a polygon."));



var layerControlLayers = [
    {
        name: 'KG1',
        layer: fg1
    },
    {
        name: 'KG2',
        layer: fg2
    },
    {
        name: 'EG',
        layer: fg3
    },
]

//layerIdx: start counting with 0 = KG1
new L.LayerControl(layerControlLayers, {layerIdx: 2}).addTo(map)

map.on('layercontrolUp', function(e){
    console.log(e);
});

map.on('layercontrolDown', function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```